# Move Files Recursively but only if they are not open by another process

Tags: recursive, move

I want to modify the script text below, to change the file permissions, owner and move it, only if the file is not open by another process.

```
cd /mnt/usbdrive/DVR
sudo chown 777 -R /mnt/usbdrive
sudo chmod 777 -R /mnt/usbdrive
find .  -mindepth 2 -type f -name '*.ts' -exec mv -t /mnt/usbdrive {} +
```

Comment: which operating system are you using ? Linux has the `fuser` command for that, usually packaged in "psmisc"

Comment: Ubuntu 18. I attempted to use fuser but couldn't sort out how to format the conditional statement.

Answer (score 0):

A simple and lean `find` command for your case could be:

```bsh
find .  -mindepth 2 -type f -name '*.ts' -exec fuser -s {} \; -a -exec mv /mnt/usbdrive {} \;
```

Here we take advantage of `find`’s expression abilities: note the `-a` operator (meaning “and”) so that `mv` gets executed only if `fuser` exits with 0, meaning that the file is open.

This is the safest command, capable of dealing with any character possibly present in your files's names.

But this command can also be very slow if you have many files in that directory. In fact you had used the `{} +` syntax along `mv`’s `-t` option to ease that burden.

Unfortunately we cannot just use that syntax for the two `-exec` actions, because `fuser` would exit with 0 when *any one* of the indicated files are open, and we wouldn’t even know which files are, among those provided as its arguments by `find`.

We can still use the `{} +` syntax here too, but we need a more complicated command. One like this:

```bsh
find . -mindepth 2 -type f -name '*.ts' -exec fuser {} + 2>&1 | sed 's/^\(.\+\):.*/\1/' | xargs mv -t /mnt/usbdrive
```

Breaking down what’s being `-exec`uted by `find`, we basically have `fuser` consider all files in one run but also filter its output through sed to get only the file names (`fuser` outputs PIDs along with file names) to finally pipe them to an `xargs` running your original `mv` command in one go. For testing I would recommend adding the `-p` option to such `xargs` to see what would be moved if confirmed.

Then, I also notice you say you’d like to change permissions and owner *besides* moving the file only if it is not open, but then I see you do a `chown` plus `chmod` to whole directory beforehand. (As a side note, `chown 777` does not make sense at all, you want to put a username there.. unless 777 is indeed a user-id in your system, but I doubt it).

So if you’d rather wish to do as you said, you might add those commands to the `xargs` by packing them in a shell’s compound command.

Like this:

```bsh
find . -mindepth 2 -type f -name '*.ts' -exec fuser {} + 2>&1 | sed -e 's/^\(.\+\):.*/\1/' | xargs sh -c 'echo sudo chmod 777 "${@}"; echo sudo chown user "${@}"; echo mv -t /mnt/usbdrive "${@}"' --
```

This actually only *shows* the commands that would be run. I would recommend to experiment with it, and when you’re ready to really apply it just remove the `echo`s.

**Important note:** these latter two commands allowing the use of `find`'s `{} +` syntax cannot deal with file names having embedded newlines because of the filtering done by `sed`. Dealing with those is possible but would get even more complex because of `fuser`’s particular output. I think it’s reasonable to assume your file names do not have newlines embedded, otherwise you might rather use the first simpler though slower command.